# Deploying a cloud9 based rails application to a local linux server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, git, web-deployment

I have developed an application on rails using bootstrap and other gems on cloud9 (www.c9.io) , I have mysql database with seeded data. Now I want to deploy it on a local sever, which won't be connected to internet(just to access by the department). Can anyone tell me how to go about it, Like what are the steps I need to take to deploy it successfully and also how would I handle the database linked with my application. I am also maintaining a git repo of the same on github.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would use git to clone (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) the repository onto a machine which does have access to the internet, then transfer the files via flash drive or some other hardware. Once you have the application on the local server, make sure rails is installed and you can simply start up your rails app in situ.

You can use `mysqldump` to copy your seeded database into a single file, then transfer that file to the local server and copy it using the `restore` command. This tutorial has helped me before: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/